# Error inflating maps with Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I followed the steps to create a Google Map with API V2 according to this example:

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-current-location-in-google-maps-using-api-v2-with-supportmapfragment/

I obtained de API key and tested on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (real device)

This is the Android Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.localizaciongooglemapv2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<permission
    android:name="android.localizaciongooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.localizaciongooglemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="android.localizaciongooglemapv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="MyAPIKey"/> <!--I'm sure It's correct-->
   <!--  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />--> <!-- I thought this was the problem but It is not-->
</application>
```

This is my Main Activity:

```
    package android.localizaciongooglemapv2;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        // Showing status
        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        // Setting latitude and longitude in the TextView tv_location
        tvLocation.setText("Latitude:" +  latitude  + ", Longitude:"+ longitude );

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

And I'm getting this in the error log:

```
11-06 12:09:03.714: D/AndroidRuntime(24366): Shutting down VM
11-06 12:09:03.714: W/dalvikvm(24366): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416842a0)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.localizaciongooglemapv2/android.localizaciongooglemapv2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:308)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.localizaciongooglemapv2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    ... 11 more
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
11-06 12:09:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(24366):    ... 21 more
11-06 12:09:03.749: I/Process(24366): Sending signal. PID: 24366 SIG: 9
```

I have searched a lot of info everywhere, here in stackoverflow or in the comments of the link and I cannot get a solution. Could you help me?? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare the schema twice. fragment declaration should be like bellow on activity_main.xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

And on the Manifest file you have to add the meta information about gms version. So add API_KEY as well as gms version within the application tag

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="YOUR MAP API KEY HERE" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Wish best of luck...

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to load the map:

```
private void setUpMap() {

        googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        }
```

xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

For more info, follow this great tutorial:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/